# Error when using Angular 2 bindings to inject a service

Tags: javascript, angular, babeljs

I have this script that I am converting to es5 using babel

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

class Images {
  getImagesURLs() {
      return ["images/Desert.jpg", "images/Chrysanthemum.jpg", "images/Hydrangeas.jpg", "images/Jellyfish.jpg", "images/Lighthouse.jpg"];
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  bindings: [Images]
})
@View({
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
})
export class Home {
  constructor(images) {
    this.images = images.getImagesURLs();
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> Cannot resolve all parameters for Home(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

Do I need to change this code somehow? Or maybe a Babel or SystemJS configuration?

Comment: Please retitle your question to something that describes the problem you're having.

Comment: Feel free to edit the tags if you think it's not appropriate

Comment: The tags, the title, the question. Why are you referring to ES2015?

Comment: The only resources I can find for the problem are all using TypeScript, I wanted to make it clear that this is not a TypeScript issue.

Comment: `images:Images` is not ECMAScript of any version, but it is valid TypeScript.

Comment: I get the same issue when I just use `(images)`, I'm not sure how to get it to work without TypeScript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89852/discussion-between-anotherdev-and-amit).

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty old example.

Back in the day, where you had atScript, you could achieve that with traceur (not so sure about babel). You could tell it to activate typing and annotation so that code would work perfectly without Typescript.

Today, if you want to achieve that you need to activate stage 1 on babel and then use the proper syntax for injection:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

And then in the constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(Images) image) {}
```

If that doesn't work, you can teach babel those new tricks:

```
npm install babel-plugin-angular2-annotations
npm install babel-plugin-type-assertion
```

Finally, you can configure babel (.babelrc) like:

```
{
  "optional": ["es7.decorators"],
  plugins: [
    "angular2-annotations",
    "type-assertion"
  ]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
constructor(image:Images) {}
```